# find critical point of a trig function on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$F (x)=\sin  (3x)$ on a closed interval $[-\pi/4, \pi/3]$ I am having trouble finding the critical point I find the first derivative set it to 0 and I conclude that the critical point would be $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ however that doesn't fall within the interval my book says the critical point is $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{6}$ how do I find this?  $F'(X)=3\cos (3x) $

Comment: The critical point you find isn't in the given interval and it's not a critical point even in $\Bbb R$. You probably got your derivative wrong. Show us what you got.

Comment: Your question was reformatted. Check that the edit is correct. My comment above had in mind a different $F$ than what it is now.

Comment: $\left( \cos{3x}=0 \Leftrightarrow 3x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi n \right) \Rightarrow x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{\pi n}{3},\;\; n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I edited it I had someone explain this problem once to me but I forgot how to do it and my first derivative was correct.

Comment: @ashabasha Your edit isn't clear. What is $F(x)$? Is it $\sin(3x)$?

Comment: @ashabasha Still not clear because of reasons not worth discussing at the moment. Please answer with yes or no: is $F(x)=\sin (3x)$?

Comment: @gitgud Yes that is it

Comment: @ashabasha Check  M. Strochyk's comment above. It gives you the answer. Is there something you don't understand about it?

Comment: I see the formula so pi/2+ pin is divided by 3 and that's how you get pi/6 pin/3

Comment: Thanks I get it now! ♥♡ best tutor ever

Comment: @ashabasha I didn't do anything. My only effort was to understand what $F$ was. Glad you got it.